# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) on Android Q

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

I granted permissions but `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` returns this error:

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20200130_165131.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I want to take the last image from the gallery and save it to another file. I tested it on the Android P test device it was running on. But it returns this error in android emulator with android version Q (API level 29). What's wrong with that?

These are my code snippets:

```
writeStoragePermissionGranted();

BitmapFactory.Options options = null;
Bitmap bm = null;

String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };

    final Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver()
            .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                    null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
        String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
        File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);

        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 2;

            try {
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, options);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);



        try {
            saveImage(bm,"NAME" );
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

`writeStoragePermissionGranted()` function:

```
 public void writeStoragePermissionGranted() {
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
           if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                   == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startPeriodicRequest();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

and manifest permissions:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know there are many question about that. But no one worked on the android emulator version Q. On the other hand, this code works on android pie (API level 28)

Comment: On Android Q that path is not reachable anymore. Dont use DATA but RELATIVE_PATH instead.

Comment: @blackapps Can you explain more clearly? Maybe with an example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Android 10, they introduced the concept of "Scoped Storage" and this way, you no longer can OPEN a image using its path. You can get more info [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped).

So now you have to decode it using its `ParcelFileDescriptor` and its `Uri`.

You can:

```
final Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
        // You can replace '0' by 'cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID)'
        // Note that now, you read the column '_ID' and not the column 'DATA'
        Uri imageUri= ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cursor.getInt(0));

        // now that you have the media URI, you can decode it to a bitmap
        try (ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mediaUri, "r")) {
            if (pfd != null) {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    } else {
        // Repeat the code you already are using
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, with this code, how do I copy the file somewhere for further processing?

Answer (score 36):

Adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the **manifest**'s application block could actually solve the issue!

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem for me, easy and clean

Comment: Thanks , its saved my time... +1 from my side

Comment: this is a link for more use cases https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage you may be in need of that

Comment: requestLegacyExternalStorage is a temporary fix. Apps targeting Android 11 will ignore this attribute. It is meant to give developers time to migrate to newer implementations

Comment: At targetsdk 30 requestLegacyExternalStorage will ignore. Do you update for it?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to `Application` tag in `Manifest.xml` .

I hope the following code with help you out.

**Manifest.xml**

Add following in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Also Add:**

Add this in Application tag in Manifest.

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**Open Gallery to get image:**

```
private void openImagePicker() {
    MyDatePicker datePicker = new MyDatePicker();
    datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE PICK");
}
```

**Launch ActivityForResult:**

`onActivityResult` you will get result object through you will get image raw uri.

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> galleryResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    imageURi = data.getData();
                    image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    String path = getPath(imageURi);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                        image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

**Get Absolute path of image:**

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else return null;
}
```